# How do you set the Redis url in Resque if you're not using Rails?

Tags: redis, resque

In rails, it is easy to just add a config/resque.yml, but we're running a gem on the command line and we would like to tell it where to look for Resque jobs instead of the default localhost:6379

Right now, we run our gem by going to the gem lib and then running rake resque:work etc etc.. so how do we tell it where redis is?(redis could be in another machine in the network or in the cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by just adding `Resque.redis = 'server:port` in our gem's Rakefile, just before we included resque via `require 'resque/tasks'`

Comment: You need to `require 'resque'` first.

Answer (score 1):

Building on corroded's answer, I had to do this:

```
require "./my_class"
require "resque"
Resque.redis = 'server:port'
require "resque/tasks"
```

Comment: In order to use an URL from an environment variable, I had to include the protocol, like: `redis://192.168.1.1:6379`